# How to load Bert pretrained model with SentenceTransformers from local path?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, pre-trained-model, sentence-transformers

I am using the SentenceTransformer library to use Bert pre-trained model
I download the file in google Colabs and saved it with these commands:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking')
model.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/Pizza/Bert_Model')
```

these give me a folder with my model in it, then I download the folder and wanna use it in my local file with this code:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('Bert_Model')
```

but now it doesn't work properly and I got this error that '**NameError: name 'model' is not defined**'
How can I load the model that I have saved to a path?

Answer (score 0):

When you load your model from local file, you have to specify the **path** of the model, not its name. This means that the argument of `SentenceTransformer()` has to be the full path to the folder that contains the `config.json` file:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('/path/to/your/model')
```